# Unknown file type in ConnexientUI.framework/ConnexientUI

Tags: ios, archive

I get this error when try to create an archive for my iOS App.

```
Showing Recent Messages
Unknown file type in '/Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-app-fuarokazrfbtgrgmiljdjieoyznt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/testing/BuildProductsPath/Testing-iphoneos/ConnexientUI.framework/ConnexientUI'
```

I execute on a M1.
Any idea...